# CSS and HTML Navigation Bar Error

Tags: html, css, button, navigation, stacked

I am trying to make a basic site with HTML & CSS, with a navigation bar, but I have a problem with it [below]:

```
body
{
    background-color: #666;
}

.font_title
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#title
{
    width: 800px; 
}

#container
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 995px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#navigation_holder
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.navigation_button
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #09C;
}
.navigation_button:hover
{
    background-color: #09F;
}


<div id="container"> <!-- The main container -->
<div class="font_title", id="title"> Our Site</div>
<div id="navigation_holder">
<div id="navigation_button_1", class="navigation_button"> Home </div> 
<div id="navigation_button_2", class="navigation_button"> About </div>
<div id="navigation_button_3", class="navigation_button"> Services </div>
<div id="navigation_button_4", class="navigation_button"> Contact </div>
</div>

<!-- More DIVs in the container -->

</div>
```

The problem is - all my navigation buttons are stacked up ontop of each other, not on a row. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The problem with the page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making them divs, use anchor tags inside lists. Here's the image and the complete working code for you:

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
    background-color: #666;
}

.font_title
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#title
{
    width: 800px; 
}

#container
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 995px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#navigation_holder
{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.navigation_button
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #09C;
}
.navigation_button:hover
{
    background-color: #09F;
}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

li
{
float:left;
}


a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:200px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #09C;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color: #09F;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"> <!-- The main container -->
<div class="font_title", id="title"> Our Site</div>
<div id="navigation_holder">
<ul>
<li id="navigation_button_1" > <a href="#">  Home </a></li>
<li id="navigation_button_2" > <a href="#">  About </a></li>
<li id="navigation_button_3" > <a href="#">  Services </a></li>
<li id="navigation_button_4" > <a href="#">  Contact </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- More DIVs in the container -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After that you can style a elements further to resemble the look of your homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `div`s are block elements, thus they naturally position themselves on top of each other. You can use several methods to get them to behave. Applying a `display: inline-block` to your `.navigation_button` class is what I would prefer in most cases. In this case, however, a `float: left` will work just as well.

The two methods have their benefits and drawbacks, but floats can become problematic because they essentially become unrecognizable to non-floated elements (in the same way `position: absolute` does).

As an aside, if I were you, I'd pull the `height` off your container, change `#navigation_holder` to a `<nav>`, and perhaps even pull the `id`s (and possibly even the classes!) off of your individual navigation elements. Heck, you could even take out the inner `div`s entirely, and replace them with a `ul` whose `li` were `display: inline` (it would be more semantic).

You could then reference them like this:

```
.navigation_holder ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 40px; /* or whatever */
}
```

And if you need to target only the first or last:

```
.navigation_holder ul li:first-of-type {
    // styles
}

.navigation_holder ul li:last-of-type {
    // styles
}
```

To pop the default styles off the `ul`:

```
.navigation_holder ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A reply to your question, and a question to your question...

**What are you looking for?**

Here are 3 examples:

[image: 3 List Styles]

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhn0N.jpg)** Providing you wanted a normal left hand horizontal inline-list you would do:

**HTML**

[image: Left List]

```
<div id="navigation_holder">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation_left ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation_left ul li { display: inline; }

#navigation_left ul li a
{
font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #DDD;
background-color: #0099CF;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#navigation_left ul li a:hover
{
color: #FFF;
background-color: #00BEF9;
}
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm3mC.jpg) Providing you want to center your li elements.

**HTML**

[image: List Center]

```
   <div id="navigation_center">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation_center ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation_center ul li { display: inline; }

#navigation_center ul li a
{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #DDD;
    background-color: #0099CF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#navigation_center ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00BEF9;
}
```

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7B2R.jpg) Providing you want to center your li elements with a solid background.

**HTML**

[image: List Center Background]

```
   <div id="navigation_center_full">
    <ul class="full">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation_center_full ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #DDD;
    background-color: #0099CF;
}

#navigation_center_full ul li { display: inline; }

#navigation_center_full ul li a
{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #DDD;
    background-color: #0099CF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#navigation_center_full ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00BEF9;
}
```

Pretty sure this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use `<ul>` and `<li>` tags? I think is better. Then in CSS you must use:

```
display: inline
```

One example in: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5